# How can I see if a Timestamp is more than X days ago in Java?

Tags: java, android, firebase, date, timestamp

In my Firebase database, for each item present, I save the date of when it is created and inserted into the db.
The date is saved using the **ServerValue.TIMESTAMP**, the value is saved as a Map. How can I compare the saved value to today's current date in Java?

I need to know if the date of the item is older than 14 days. THX

[image]

Comment: How are those dates represented in Java?

Comment: They are represented as Map

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Compare timestamp with actual time (Java)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14292463/compare-timestamp-with-actual-time-java)

Comment: You'll be wanting `Instant.ofEpochSecond`.

Comment: I need to know if the date of the item is older than 14 days

Comment: I don't know Firebase (only at a high level) but storing dates as Map doesn't seem right. I'd assume you'd use Map to store objects which could _contain_ dates and thus the dates would be values in a map though. When you load those into Java I for sure can't imagine a date itself is represented as a `Map<String, Object>` or so.

Comment: Yes, it is saved as 'Map<String, Object>'

Comment: @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic- `Instant.ofEpochMilli()` since the timestamp has 13 digits, not just 10.

Comment: Reading the documentation it looks like `ServerValue.TIMESTAMP` is a placeholder that would need to be resolved to get the actual value. You might want to look into how that is done. Alternatively, if you are able to compare `date` on the database try to generate a new date (maybe again by resolving `TIMESTAMP`) and subtract 14 days from it. Then send that date to the db and compare.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The number in your screenshot represents the number of milliseconds from the epoch which you can convert into an Instant using [`Instant.ofEpochMilli`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html#ofEpochMilli-long-). Once you have `Instant`, you can convert it into other date-time types e.g.

```
import java.time.Instant;
import java.time.ZoneOffset;
import java.time.ZonedDateTime;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.ofInstant(Instant.ofEpochMilli(1616686018322L), ZoneOffset.UTC);
        System.out.println(zdt);
        ZonedDateTime now = ZonedDateTime.now(ZoneOffset.UTC);
        if (now.minusDays(14).isAfter(zdt)) {
            System.out.println("The item is 14 or more days older");
        } else {
            System.out.println("The item less than 14 days older");
        }
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
2021-03-25T15:26:58.322Z
The item less than 14 days older
```

Note that the comparison shown above takes all units (up to nanoseconds precision) into account. However, if you want to compare only dates (not date & time), you can perform the comparison on [`ZonedDateTime#toLocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html#toLocalTime--).

Learn more about the modern date-time API from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

Comment: How can i compare only the days ?

Comment: `if (now.minusDays(14).toLocalDate().isAfter(zdt.toLocalDate())) { //... }`